# Vagrant Puphpet Could not find class ::puphpet::cron

Tags: vagrant, puphpet, vagrant-provision

I am actually trying to install a vagrant box for Magento and I having this issue that I could not resolve.
During `vagrant up` I have this :

```
==> magestudy: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> magestudy: Running Puppet with ...
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Info: Loading facts
==> magestudy: Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find class ::puphpet::cron for magestudy.dev at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-ec859315aae74732926620cbde081be8/puphpet/manifests/init.pp:12:3 on node magestudy.dev
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Here is my local vagrant plugins

```
vagrant-puppet-install (4.1.0)
vagrant-share (1.1.6)
vagrant-vbguest (0.13.0)
```

My local versions

```
vagrant -v Vagrant 1.9.0
VBoxManage -v 5.1.10r112026
```

I did not really find a solution on internet, maybe it is a simple one.
If more informations are needed on my configuration tell me.

Thank you !

Comment: https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2504

Comment: I already upload my `config.yml` and recreate the archive, but still have the issue... Is there some cache for this ? I did `vagrant destroy` before my `vagrant up` Do I have something else to do ? Thank you

Comment: I do that again twice, and now it seems to be working ! Not really understand the difference but it work ! Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people seeing that, as Frédéric said here is the answer https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2504
I had to re-upload my Puphpet configuration to the website and generate a new archive.